# Etherpad-lite list numering formatting

Tags: etherpad

Is it possible to set numbered list format in etherpad-lite?

Default format is:

```
1. 
1.1.
1.1.1
```

I would like to have formatting:

```
§1
1)
1.
```

UPDATE: Tried to use

```
.list-number1 li:before {
    content: "§" counter(first, decimal);
    counter-increment: first;
}
```

but all elements at first level have §1 numbering (I think there is no pure css solution for that)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the Etherpad Ordered List implementation.  it would be easy to do what you want with CSS.

Place the followin in your src/static/custom/pad.css

```
/* The behavior for incrementing and the prefix */
.list-number1 li:before {
  content: "§" counter(first);
  counter-increment: first;
}

.list-number2 li:before {
  content: counter(first) ")";
  counter-increment: second;
}

.list-number3 li:before {
  content: counter(first) ".";
  counter-increment: third 1;
}
```

Ensure when you refresh your page that it hasn't loaded the minified/cached version of custom/pad.css

I find it bizarre that this got down-voted..  OP can you please confirm this is the correct answer?

Again it's worth noting I wrote the implementation in Etherpad Core so I'm kinda familiar with this...